# Browserify/Watchify Cannot find module 'waypoints'

Tags: gulp, browserify, watchify

I'm just starting with browserify.
When it's working it's brilliant.
But `require()`...ing some modules isn't working (by default).

I have this code:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
var gsap = require('gsap');
var waypoints = require('waypoints');
```

In the above. jQuery and gsap work and are imported. But waypoints doesn't. When waypoints is included I get the error:

```
Browserify Error { [Error: Cannot find module 'waypoints' from '/Users/mk/Sites/PROJECTNAME/app/scripts']
```

This happens with some random other modules too.

All modules installed with npm.

Using the browserify/watchify recipe from this page:
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md

I have tried some fixes inspired by similar stack overflow questions but no luck so far.

Some answers suggest that there's is/was a bug with npm that might be responsible. If that's the case is there anything reliable I can do?

Happy to provide further info.

Comment: Does your waypoints module have an export?

Comment: export is not needed you can require any js without it.. I do it on a regular basis. Is waypoints in the same folder ? if yes, try "./waypoints". If not, try to specify the path to waypoints, eg "path/to/waypoints"

Comment: For now i have it working with
var waypoints = require("../../node_modules/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.js”);
(my main.js is inside ./app/scripts/)

Comment: @AdamBotley do you think i should log an issue with the waypoints.js github project to add an `export`. If i find out how to do it i might then try adding it to the project but i'm not sure how just now.

Comment: @MarkStickling I've checked that packages github - their package.json doesn't have a "main" property, which defines the main script for the package. this is what is used by `require('package_name')` to determine what is returned.

Modify the waypoints package.json file to include the property `"main": "./lib/jquery.waypoints.js"`, put the require back to `require('waypoints')` and see if that works

Comment: Thanks Adam, that works. Issue logged with waypoints.js too.

Comment: @MarkStickling, Maybe my comment might be useful for further investigations.
I've faces same issue with waypoints and created [pull request](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/pull/481). Until it accepted, I'm using my fork, where I've added ``waypoints.noframework.js`` as main entry point in ``package.json``.

On the other hand, webpack (which does similar job as browserify) has import-loader and export-loader for things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's issue

Link to thread https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues/458

use

```
require('waypoints/lib/noframework.waypoints.js')
```